# Is my singleton implementation correct? c#

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I've been reading about patterns and i am trying to implement the Singleton

Is my implementation correct? How can i Improve it? There are so many implementation on the web............

```
public sealed class SingletonProxy 
        {
            private static IInfusion instance;

            static SingletonProxy() { }

            SingletonProxy() { }

            public static IInfusion Instance
            {
                get
                {
                    if(instance == null)
                    {
                        instance = XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<IInfusion>();
                    }
                    return instance;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why this is not thread safe and how would you modify it?

Comment: As others have pointed out, you should read Jon Skeet's page on this topic. Locking, or even better, double-check locking, would help out here.

Answer (score 1):

Since we now have the [System.Lazy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx) class, I tend to use this implementation:

```
public sealed class SingletonProxy
{
    private static readonly Lazy<IInfusion> instance 
          = new Lazy<IInfusion>(XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<IInfusion>);

    public static IInfusion Instance
    {
        get { return instance.Value; }
    }
}
```